Wind force field not causing rigid body to rotate
I created a "Wind" force field, which I restricted with a tube-shaped falloff and set a maximum radius.
I'm making it blow on the side of a rigid body, expecting it to rotate.
But instead, it moves perfectly straight, even when I increase the ground friction.
Did I misconfigure something?
Thanks


I think you need to change the shape from plane to something else

I may be wrong but I don't think that it is possible, you need to cheat

I found this solution:
We can break the object into several parts and apply a 'Fixed' rigid body constraint.
This works well for simple objects, but I imagine it could quickly become cumbersome to apply constraints to all the parts of a more complex object.


nice trick!...................

I don't think that it's possible in Blender to push the side of an object with a force field, you neet to cheat, for example push the object with another rigid body or simply keyframe its movement.
